# Problems when assigning dictionary items with for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, assign

```
head = {
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":4,
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -0.1044968729335983,
               51.52014078866054
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "description":"Фаррингдон-стрит",
            "iconCaption":"Фаррингдон-стрит",
            "marker-color":"#b51eff"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

My first item in list in always this(below)

```
head['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0] = long
head['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][1] = lat



zone = {
   "type":"Feature",
   "id":0,
   "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[]
   },
   "properties":{
      "description":"Вокзал Паддингтон",
      "fill":"#ff931e",
      "fill-opacity":0.3,
      "stroke":"#e6761b",
      "stroke-width":"2",
      "stroke-opacity":0.9
   }
}
```

So this is my code. It recognizes number of addresses I need and append that much items to the list

```
for i in range (0, len(lst)):
   head['features'].append(zone)
```

Somehow I get coordinates and store it in list lst[]. When Im trying to replace it with code:

```
for k in range (0, (len (lst)) ):
  head['features'][k+1]['geometry']['coordinates'] = lst[k]['data-points']
```

It replaces the all item in 'coordinate' with the last item in list lst[].
Weird problem. But when i do it manually in python shell it works.

Comment: What is  `lst`?  You didn't show that in your example.

Comment: Please show your lst

Comment: It is list of coordinates like : [[78.38356427773662, 45.02003438820365], [78.39008741006084, 45.020125699935626], [78.39030198678205, 45.01839075197834]]